# How to read word and integers from a line in a file

Tags: java, string, file, io, integer

I have a code here:-

```
package testFiles;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadFile {
public static void main(String[] args){
    FileReader in=null;
    FileWriter out=null;
    String line;
    File fp=new File("readFrom.txt");
    try {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(fp);
        //System.out.println(sc.next());
        if(sc.next().contentEquals("Coding")){
            System.out.println("####");
            while(sc.next().contentEquals("\n")==false){
                if(sc.nextInt()==1){
                    System.out.println("Coding is set.");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Coding is not set.");
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

**What i intent to do**:I want to read a word from the file say "Coding". There will an integer after a space after this word.ie. the file would be:
`Coding 1`
On reading 'Coding' the program should read the corresponding number and return 'set' if the number is 1,and 'not set' if the number is not 1.

**My problem:** I can read the string and verify if it's Coding.But i cant get the number.

**what i want**:I want the program to read the string and also the number corresponding and return statements based on the conditions.Remember the word
"Coding" and the number are in the same line.
Please Guide me.

Comment: remove the while loop you have 2 tokens but you are trying to read 3 token

Comment: `sc.next().contentEquals("\n")` -> `next()` ignores delimiters and by default delimiters are all whitespaces including tabulators and line separators so `\n` will never be read by `next`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `sc.hasNext();` to your while condition. `sc.next();` will read next value and you will lose it while checking your condition. I also add some suggestions about stream close operation on `finally`.

> Code at the below prints:

```
Coding
Coding is set.
```

> "readFrom.txt" has text: "Coding 1"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    FileReader in = null;
    FileWriter out = null;
    File fp = new File("D:/readFrom.txt");
    Scanner sc = null;
    try {
        sc = new Scanner(fp);
        String str = "";
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            str = sc.next();
            if (str.contentEquals("Coding")) {
                System.out.println(str);
                if (sc.nextInt() == 1) {
                    System.out.println("Coding is set.");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Coding is not set.");
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

        try {
            if (out != null)
                out.close(); // you should close it on finally
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            if (in != null)
                in.close(); // you should close it on finally
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            if (sc != null)
                sc.close(); // you should close it on finally
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir, that helped me.Also i would like to know how to replace 1 with 0 or vice-a-versa in the same text file and in the same line.So that i can change the set or not set condition dynamically.

Comment: After `System.out.println(str);` assaing sc.nextInt() to an integer value: `int i = sc.nextInt(); if (i == 0 || i == 1);` // this means if "read value" is 1 or 0 do the same operation.

Comment: Sir, sorry but my question is that how to delete that 1 and place 0 instead of 1 in its place.So the text will be `Coding 0` instead of `Coding 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Sample Code

```
    while(sc.hasNext()){
        try{
           String str = sc.nextLine();
           String strArray[] = str.split(" ");
           if ( strArray.length > 1 &&  strArray[0].equals("Coding")){
               int count = Integer.parseInt(strArray[1]);
               // check for count value == 1 or  not and do processing
               if ( count == 1){
                    System.out.println("Coding set");
               }else{
                   System.out.println("Coding not set");
               }
           }else{
                System.out.println("Coding not set");
           }
         }catch(Exception err){
             err.printStackTrace();
         }
    }
```